# Модуль Pandas проблема с преобразованием json => csv

Tags: python, json, pandas, requests

У меня есть код, который авторизуется на сайте после чего идет в catalog_tree.json и оттуда вытягивает данные. Дело в том что мне нужно конвертировать json в csv файл дабы потом эти данные импортировать на наш сайт и появились категории, но сайт куда производится импорт ругается на то что не может понять где находится подкатегория. Я думаю что проблема в этих кавычках, ибо судя по первому скрину у меня есть сначала строка childrens а потом она исчезает и появляется только в подкатегории, в общем буду благодарен помощи в решении данного вопроса.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
authResponse = requests.request("POST", authUrl, headers=headers, data=authPayload)  # Генерация и отправка запроса

data = authResponse.json()  # Заносим ответ в ячейку data
session = "'session':" + data['session']  # Выделяем из ответа сессию и заносим в отдельную ячейку
if data['success'] == True:
    print('Успешная авторизация на сервере!')
    print('Ваша сессия: ' + data['session'])
else:
    print('Авторизация не удалась')

catalogPayload = session  # Заносим куки в гет запрос для вытягивания каталога

catalogResponse = requests.request("GET", catalogUrl, headers=headers, data=catalogPayload)  # Создаем гет запрос на урл каталога
catalogData = catalogResponse.json()  # Конвертируем ответ в json

categoryDetaliPCRaw = catalogData[4]  #Выделяем нужную нам категорию
categoryDetaliPC = json.dumps(categoryDetaliPCRaw)
print(categoryDetaliPC)

csvConvert = pd.read_json(categoryDetaliPC)  #Пытаемся конвертировать файл из JSON в CSV
csvConvert.to_csv(r'C:\Users\BOX\Desktop\test\pcdetaly.csv', index = None)
```

Результат в консоль: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

И получается сам csv файл:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Ну у вас тут иерархическая структура. Не очень понятно, как такое дерево преобразовывать в плоскую таблицу.

Comment: Мне нужно выделять из главной категории подкатегории и после чего уже все соединять в одной переменной для вывода или как можно поступить?

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста в вопросе [mcve] входных данных (__в виде текста / CSV / Python кода или ссылки на файл__) и __то что вы ожидаете получить на выходе__. Также советую ознакомиться: [Как наиболее эффективно задать вопрос, связанный с обработкой и/или анализом данных (например: по Pandas / Numpy / SciPy / SciKit Learn / SQL)](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/7060/)